# Radical and Centric not Essential P-group

Tags: finite-groups

I'm looking that in the Fusion System categories, the p-subgroups that are essential, are centric (by definition) and radical (by implication of the definition), but I want to know if there is an example about a p-subgroup that is radical and centric, but not essential. Anyone knows an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take any prime $p$, and consider the fusion system for ${\rm GL}(4,p)$ ( ie objects the $p$-subgroups of ${\rm GL}(4,p)$ morphisms induced by conjugations).
Take a maximal parabolic $P$ such that $P/U \cong {\rm GL}(3,p)$, where $U$ is the unipotent radical of $P$. Then $U$ is centric and radical but is not essential (as ${\rm GL}(3,p)$ has no strongly $p$-embedded subgroup).

Comment: Is there any other smaller than this one? (Only curiosity)

Comment: Well, I suppose the parabolic $P$ itself is a smaller example. In general, the smallest example, whatever it is, will be the fusion system of  genuine group $G$ with $U = O_{p}(G)$ elementary Abelian and $C_{G}(U) = U$, such that $G/U$ has no strongly embedded subgroup. A candidate might be the case that $p = 2$, $U$ elementary of order $8$, and $G/U \cong {\rm GL}(3,2)$, but I have not checked.

Comment: I meant "strongly $p$-embedded" in the last result.

Comment: Can you say me the reference where you got this example?

Comment: From no reference, just from understanding the definitions.

Comment: Well, so can you say me your name to give you merit? I want to add this example to mi undergraduate thesis.

Comment: My name is G.R. Robinson, but there is nothing new in what I am saying.

Comment: Maybe there is anything new in your example, but I didn't found it by myself, because I don't have a wide view of the GL's groups as you, so that's the reason of the merit.

Comment: Can you explain me why is your idea correct? I don't understand the structure of maximal parabolic and unpotent radical subgroups.

Comment: I think you have to do some reading. But if you look at the case of $G/U \cong {\rm GL}(3,2)$ this quotient is a group of order 168, and it has two conjugacy classes of maximal parabolic subgroups each isomorphic to $S_{4}$. These have index $7$ of course, so they are not strongly ($2$)-embedded ( as when $Y$ is a strongly $p$-embedded subgroup of $Y$, we have that $[Y:X] i \equiv 1$ (mod $p^{a}$) where $p^{a}$ is the order of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In which book can I read about the concepts you're using?

Comment: Suzuki, or Aschbacher- well-known texts on finite group theory ( there are many others- Carter, for finite groups of Lie type).

Comment: By curiosity, are you the Geoffrey Robinson of the paper "Amalgams, blocks, weights, fusion systems and finite simple groups"? (I'm studying it in my thesis and just noticed about the full name).

Comment: Yes, I am the author of that paper. Some parts of it could be proved much more efficiently!

Comment: Can you say me about where to read about maximal parabolic and unipotent radical subgroups to understand the example?

Comment: I gave some references in the comment above. About parabolic subgroups, the book of Carter may be the closest of that list. You need to read about groups with a $(B,N)$-pair. As I said, there are many choices. There are good surveys, for example, by C.W. Curtis.